# Не могу найти ошибку в if python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7, bs4

Вот сам код.

```
import traceback
import requests
import dateparser
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

                                                #Парсер v2 BETA by Raha
def get_html(url): # <Остается
    r = requests.get(url)
    if r.ok: # 200  ## 403 404
        return r.text
    print(r.status_code)

def get_page_link(html): # <  Собираем главнные новости.
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    title =soup.find('h1',{'class':'roboto'}).text
    link_containers=soup.findAll('div',{'class':'cat_news_item'})

# < Этот цикл отбирает только ссылки на главные новости.
    counter = 0
    links_rcv = []
    for link_container in link_containers:
        a_tag = link_container .find("a")
        # Если нашел
        if a_tag:
            link = a_tag.get("href")
            links_rcv.append(f'https://www.zakon.kz{link}')
            #print(f'https://www.zakon.kz{link}')
        else:
            counter += 1

    return links_rcv


def get_context_html(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    return r.text


def get_context_data(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    mainblock = soup.find('div',{'class':'fullnews white_block'})  # < Получаем контекст.


    if mainblock is not None:  # < Если контекст не пуст, продолжаем разбор.
        item_title = mainblock.find('h1').text
        item_datetime = mainblock.find('span',{'class':'news_date'}).text
        item_text = mainblock.findAll('p')
        dateparser.parse(item_datetime, date_formats=['%d %B %Y %H']) # < Конвентирует формат времени удобный в SQL
    else:  # < Иначе получаем и разбираем контекст другого типа.
        mainblock = soup.find('div',{'class':'full_story'})
        item_title = soup.find('title').text
        item_datetime = mainblock.find('div',{'class':'news_date'}).text
        item_text = mainblock.findAll('p',{'class':'MsoNormal'})
        dateparser.parse(item_datetime, date_formats=['%d %B %Y %H']) # < Конвентирует формат времени удобный в SQL

    return (item_title,item_datetime,item_text)  # < Возвращаем результат, вне зависимости от типа страницы.


def main():
    url = 'https://www.zakon.kz/news/'
    links_rcv = get_page_link(get_html(url))
    for i in links_rcv:
        try:
            print(get_context_data(get_context_html(i)))
        except:
            print(f'Ошибка на странице: {i}')
            print(traceback.format_exc())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Суть проблемы в том что при выводе.Некоторые страницы парсятся  а некоторые нет.В чем могла быть ошибка ? Я думаю из-за разных структур страниц.Хотя в условии прописано это.Но все же не могу понять

**UPD** об этом иффе идет речь

```
if mainblock is not None:  # < Если контекст не пуст, продолжаем разбор.
    item_title = mainblock.find('h1').text
    item_datetime = mainblock.find('span',{'class':'news_date'}).text
    item_text = mainblock.findAll('p')
    dateparser.parse(item_datetime, date_formats=['%d %B %Y %H']) # < Конвентирует формат времени удобный в SQL
else:  # < Иначе получаем и разбираем контекст другого типа.
    mainblock = soup.find('div',{'class':'full_story'})
    item_title = soup.find('title').text
    item_datetime = mainblock.find('div',{'class':'news_date'}).text
    item_text = mainblock.findAll('p',{'class':'MsoNormal'})
    dateparser.parse(item_datetime, date_formats=['%d %B %Y %H']) # < Конвентирует формат времени удобный в SQL
```

Comment: О каком именно `if` идёт речь в кратком описании вопроса?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`a_tag = link_container .find("a")`

Пробел перед `.find` - так и задумано?

После выполнения текущего кода, получены следующие ошибки:

```py
Ошибка на странице: https://www.zakon.kz/4980772-advokaty-i-nds.html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/OFFICE-4/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/Scripts/parsing.py", line 64, in main
    print(get_context_data(get_context_html(i)))
  File "C:/Users/OFFICE-4/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/Scripts/parsing.py", line 52, in get_context_data
    item_datetime = mainblock.find('div',{'class':'news_date'}).text
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Как видно из описания, не может корректно найти `item_datetime`.

Проблема не в `if`, а в том, что `mainblock = soup.find('div',{'class':'full_story'})` не содержит элемента `item_datetime = mainblock.find('div',{'class':'news_date'}).text`

Comment: Перенесите свой ответ в комментарий к вопросу

Comment: @strawdog не могу, репы не хватает :)

Comment: Ну теперь и не нужно, теперь ваш ответ действительно выглядит как ответ.